# Efficient search for shortest and longest strings from an array of long strings in C

Tags: c, algorithm, string

Given an array of pointers to ordinary C NUL-terminated (and typically very long) strings, how can we best find the smallest and the largest strings?

Comment: What do you mean `array of pointers to strings`? (remember there is no string in `C`) Do you mean what you say or simply `array of char *`?

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify this by settling on the simplest and most C-like meaning, which is an array of `char *`, each of which points to a typical C NUL terminated string. If my edit is wrong, I encourage Vish to roll it back (and earn a badge to boot).

Answer (score 9):

using [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strlen/) on each entry of your array.

Comment: -1 Even if true, it may not be clear why this is an 'efficient' search. An explanation why there is no more efficient way would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe for looping through them will help? - Ok, you don't want C++ idea, let's see:

Ok, again:

```
char **strings; // initialized
int stringsNumber = 500; // number of string in first dimension
int longestLen = 0;
int shortestLen = MAX_INT; // or other REALLY BIG number ;]
char *longest = NULL;
char *shortest = NULL;
int current = 0;
for(int i =0; i < stringsNumber; i++)
{
  current = strlen(strings[i]);
  if(current > longestLen) { longestLen = current; longest = strings[i];  }
  if(current < shortestLen) { shortestLen = current; shortest = strings[i]; }
}
```

Comment: The question is about an array of pointers, not a vector of strings.

Comment: where do you find difference in idea? it could be array of strings in php, way would be the same.

Comment: Your code finds largest and smallest length of strings, not strings. And, don't use stringsNumber if you have std::vector.

Comment: again, i'm showing the IDEA, not the target implementation. if you can't upvote, please at least not downvote. i've edited my comment to reflect your requests.

Comment: Also, initialize longest and shortest - if all strings is empty longest and shortest will be uninitialized.

Comment: `int shortestLen` shouldn't be initialized to MAX_INT or you won't find anything shorter than that.  Actually the lengths should be `size_t`, so you should use SSIZE_MAX.

Comment: max_int edited, for the size_t i would argue, but you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You can have another array of char pointers of size n, with its ith pointer pointing to the start of the ith string.

Increment each pointer till it reaches the end.

The first one to reach the end was the pointer to the shortest string.

The last one to reach the end was the pointer to the longest string.

Comment: This is clever, but it still looks at every character of every string, so it doesn't beat the naïve approach of calling `strlen` once per string.

Answer (score 1):

If the strings are really really long, you should consider saving them with a length attribute, which is computed already during entering the strings.

Answer (score 0):

If it's given to you and you don't manage it - iteration over array and `strlen`.

If you manage it - consider using `std::string` or `pair<char *, int>`(string,length) to optimize your code  as well as replacing array of pointers with some ordered container.

Comment: Last time I checked, those were not part of C.

Comment: +1. Detail of language choice aside, this answer makes a valid point. Often the best optimization is to find another way to do it entirely. Here, the suggestion is to use a slightly more complicated string representation that retains length as well as the characters themselves. That makes the cost O(n) where n is the size of the array, instead of O(n*m) where m is the average length of the string.